# Using the new java time API with floating points

Tags: java, datetime

I am looking at the new `java.time.*` API. It seems very convenient to work with, much more so than the old `java.util.Date` API. My only problem is the following: I consider some models describing durations which internally use functions evaluating to `double`s describing the non-integral amount of seconds which has passed. Can I somehow construct/manipulate `Duration` / `LocalDateTime` objects using floating points (which should then be converted to appropriate second/millisecond/nanosecond durations)?

Comment: Be aware that floating point is always an approximation. The textual representation of `"" + 0.20` may well have several digits. So not parsing, but multiplication and rounding seems the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have given this some thought and I have come up with two methods:

Firstly, as [J Richard Snape](https://stackoverflow.com/users/838992/j-richard-snape) pointed out it is possible to create a String which then can be parsed into a floating point like so:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
df.setMaximumFractionDigits(8);

String dateString = df.format(val);

if(dateString.startsWith(".")) {
    dateString = "0" + dateString;
}

Duration.parse("PT" + dateString + "s");
```

The whole shenanigans are required because the `Duration` class is rather picky about how a valid floating point sequence should look like, in particular it seems to have to start with a digit and scientific notation is not allowed.

As an alternative the following one-liner will do reasonably well:

```
Duration.ofNanos((long) (val * 1e9));
```

Obviously some decimals are cut off (and I guess an overflow might be possible?!), however for my purposes this is accurate enough.

The main advantage of the latter approach is the performance: For a sample of 10,000,000 randomly generated values the String parsing takes about 20 seconds on my machine, whereas the creation from nanoseconds only takes about 0.3 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this yet, but it appears you could use [`Duration.parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-).  Format your `double` variables as strings appropriately, e.g.

```
String dateString = "PT"+Double.toString(yourDouble)+"s";
Duration myDuration = Duration.parse(dateString);
```

You can then get seconds, milliseconds etc from the `Duration` object.

Comment: I must say that I am not entirely pleased with the approach. The performance seems to be a problem in my setup.

Comment: Can you elaborate - what do you mean by performance is a problem? It is slow, or it fails? Working example here on ideone - http://ideone.com/x24raa

Comment: Well, just saying that parsing takes a long time. For instance `Duration.ofMillis(Math.round(1000 * myDouble))` is a *lot* faster

Comment: OK - fair enough.  You can always add another answer if you like (I think [answering your own question is encouraged round here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)), explaining that you've found it quicker - or edit it into mine as an alternative (I'd be happy to approve such an edit).  It's certainly new knowledge to me that `ofMillis` is a lot faster, so your research might help someone else.